# What's the best way to set up SUM or UX KPIs for a long-term project?

Tags: ux-designer, project, expert-interface

I'm working on a long-term expert level industrial software as a lead UX designer. We would like to implement and measure a set of key performance indicators (KPIs) for overall UX quality or SUM.

What's the best way to go about this? Can you give me an example of how to determine what methodologies and KPIs should be measured over time?
Thanks!

Comment: You should probably define SUM as this could be interpreted in multiple ways.

Answer (score 1):

What have you thought of so far?

Do you have a mechanism within the software which allows user feedback?  If not, you should implement one.  It should be obvious to the user how to use the feedback mechanism, and it should have a message on it that encourages user feedback, e.g. "We'd love to hear what you think of this software, please let us know, particularly if you have a usability issue".  Then you can track the amount of feedback you get.  You can then track number of users that are having usability issues, and the number of issues you have corrected.

Comment: Why I appreciate qualitative user feedback (we already do a regular SUS), I'm looking more for an empiric indicator of usability and task effectiveness over time.

Answer (score 0):

Common KPIs used to measure UX effectiveness over time are:

- [Task Success Rate](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/success-rate-the-simplest-usability-metric/)
- [Time on Task](https://measuringu.com/task-times/) (task efficiency)
- [Error Rate](https://measuringu.com/errors-ux/)
- Error Recover-ability
- Customer Satisfaction

Tracking these metrics over time involves conducting a set of usability tests to get a benchmark and then conducting the usability tests again with each release, feature improvement, or hotfix. The error rates can be identified through analytics or logging instead of usability testing, but the ability to recover would go back to a set of usability tests.

Customer Satisfaction is a qualitative metric typically tracked through surveys like the net promoter score and others.